# Why are there only two PS commands in window git Bash? As shown in the figure

Tags: git, command, git-bash

I want all the information, just like in Linux. Can this be done with other plug-ins or configuration?

[image]

Comment: I do not understand your need. Are you looking for options to `ps` ? like `ps -A` ?

Comment: I want to show all processes, but here are two. I've tried the - a parameter, but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you re-phrase your question to indicate that ? also : copying text (from a terminal) is better than pasting a screen capture

Comment: `ps` only shows processes with a controlling terminal by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to use a windows specific utility, list `tasklist.exe`, if you want to list the live processes of your Windows system in a terminal or a script.

You may also look at other ways to have a linux-ey interface in Windows, like activating WSL on your system, or using Cygwin.

---

I don't know the details of how `ps` is implemented in the version installed by default with git-bash, and what choices were made about which and what windows processes are listed in it,
I think you will have to live with the fact that some things will not work the same on Windows than on linux.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the ps -W option:
[image]